# Android onClick checkbox not checked in listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am working on **Customized ListView** using **CheckBox**. I tried to check single selection CheckBox when we click in Item of **ListView**. How can I do it?

My `XML code`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/addressTXT"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Price" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/addressCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/addressTXT"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
```

and Click Item in `BaseAdapter`.

```
         itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

How can I do it?

Comment: user RadioButton and change background by using custom selector to make it look like checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhhh I faced same issue :)
I solved this thing like below.

```
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {

                View view = parent.getChildAt(i);
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.CheckBox);
                checkBox.setChecked(false);

            }

            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.CheckBox);
            checkBox.setChecked(true);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        CheckBox box = v.findViewById(R.id.addressCheckBox); //get your checkbox
        box.setChecked(!box.isChecked()); //toggle checkbox-state
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to pun onClickListener for checkBox, not on whole view.
and second, in XML for adapter you have to put this for checkBox

```
android:focusable="true"
android:clickable="true"
```

if you need separate clickListeners for check box and for listView row you need this parameters in XML for checkBox

```
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="true"
```